# Volume changes during AVAudioPlayer playback

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am playing a short wav file using `AVAudioPlayer`.  The sound is replayed every couple of seconds from an `NSTimer` method.  The first time the sound is played, the volume is fine but on subsequent plays the volume is so low that it is almost inaudible.  Occasionally the volume drop occurs halfway through the first play.  This is happening on an iPad 3, so speaker selection isn't an issue.

```
NSError *phoneCallError;
NSURL *phoneCallUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/phone-calling-1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
AVAudioPlayer *phoneCallPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:phoneCallUrl error:&phoneCallError];
if (phoneCallError) {
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", self, phoneCallError);
} else {
    phoneCallPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
}
```

The `NSTimer` method just calls `[phoneCallPlayer play]`.  At no time is the volume set programmatically.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other sounds or recordings going on at any time when the play method might be called?

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Have you found a way to revert the volume?

Comment: i have a repeating audio and ios simulator always drops volume after first loop. i tried it on a real iphone and volume didn't drop. try with a real device.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)volumeDidChange:(UISlider *)slider {
//Handle the slider movement
[audioPlayer setVolume:[slider value]];
```

}

should be slider minimum value 0 and maximum 1.

Comment: There is no UISlider for the user to interact with.  Volume changes independently of user interaction.

Comment: Same here with Swift 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076669/avaudioplayer-volume-drops-after-couple-of-seconds