# AVAudioplayer: Volume drops after couple of seconds

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudioplayer

I've implemented an audioplayer on iOS 10.2.1 with XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

When the song starts playing the volume drops quite a bit after a couple of seconds.

Has anyone experienced such an effect?

```
 do {
     myAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
     myAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
     myAudioPlayer.volume = 1.0
 } catch  {
     print(error)
 }
```

Comment: I still observe this issue with iOS 10.3.1 and Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: this seems to be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014578/volume-changes-during-avaudioplayer-playback

Comment: i have a repeating audio and ios simulator always drops volume after first loop. i tried it on a real iphone and volume didn't drop. try with a real device.